# Comparing lambda expressions in C# with the help of ToString

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, moq, assert

I'm trying to Assert 2 Linq Expressions in a test. I'm using Moq and on callback capture the expression which was invoked inside the method under test.

```
Expression<Func<Role, bool>> actualExpression = null;
roleRepositoryMock.Setup(t => t.Search(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Role, bool>>>()))
            .Callback((Expression<Func<Role, bool>> exp) =>
                {
                    actualExpression = exp;
                })
            .Returns(new List<Role> { new Role { Name = "site1_code_role1", Description = "descr" }, new Role { Name = "site1_code" } });
```

I then compare this next way:

```
var siteCode = "site1";
var namePattern = "role1";
Expression<Func<Role, bool>> expectedExpression = 
                    t => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(siteCode)
                          || t.Name.StartsWith(siteCode + "_") 
                          || t.Name == siteCode) 
                          && t.Name.Contains(namePattern);
Assert.AreEqual(expectedExpression.ToString(), actualExpression.ToString());
```

The above Assert fails. Expected expression to string is equal to:

```
t => (((IsNullOrEmpty(value(BL.Tests.RolesServiceTests+<>c__DisplayClass6).siteCode) OrElse t.Name.StartsWith((value(BL.Tests.RolesServiceTests+<>c__DisplayClass6).siteCode + "_"))) OrElse (t.Name == value(BL.Tests.RolesServiceTests+<>c__DisplayClass6).siteCode)) AndAlso t.Name.Contains(value(BL.Tests.RolesServiceTests+<>c__DisplayClass6).namePattern))
```

And actual expression is equal to:

```
t => (((IsNullOrEmpty(value(BL.Services.RolesService+<>c__DisplayClass3).site) OrElse t.Name.StartsWith((value(BL.Services.RolesService+<>c__DisplayClass3).site + "_"))) OrElse (t.Name == value(BL.Services.RolesService+<>c__DisplayClass3).site)) AndAlso t.Name.Contains(value(BL.Services.RolesService+<>c__DisplayClass3).pattern))
```

The differences are in:

- c_*DisplayClass6 and c*_DisplayClass3
- BL.Services.RolesService and BL.Tests.RolesServiceTests (namespace different)

Could anyone explain or send me in the right direction on why and how to solve it?
Maybe it is an absolutely wrong way to try and compare these via ToString()? Alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to write tests which validate the externally observable behavior of a piece of code without being coupled to implementation details. By converting the expression to a string, you are coupling your test not only to your exact expression, but also to the implementation of the `ToString` method, which is probably subject to change in future .NET versions.

A better approach is to assert on some output state. It looks like you want to verify that the linq expression passed into your repository will filter out the right `Role` collection. Since you can already capture the expression via a callback, why not write some tests against this expression?

Assuming `Role` is a [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object), it should be trivial to write tests which invoke the expression with different collections of `Role` inputs and assert that the correct output is produced. If the expression is complex you may need many inputs, but it would look something like this:

```
var roles = new List<Role>
{
    new Role { Name = siteCode+"_role1"  },
    new Role { Name = siteCode+"_role22"  },
    new Role { Name = siteCode+"_role1324"  },
};

Assert.AreEqual(2, roles.Where(actualExpression.Compile()).Count()); //test the number of roles returned is as expected
```

Better still would be to test only at the interface of the client code, without the test having any knowledge of how the repository is queried.

Comment: That's a good proposal. I guess I was trying to escape the set up of object relations (would it be a collection of objects in that case) to run the expression against.